# finally catch or return instance or null reference

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, jakarta-mail

Using [GNU NNTP](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/), how can I get `getMessage(String newsgroup, int i)` to return either with a bona-fide `javax.mail.Message` or a null such `Message`?

```
init:
Deleting: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/USENET/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/USENET/build/built-jar.properties
Deleted 1 out of date files in 0 seconds
Compiling 2 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/USENET/build/classes
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[eclipselink.canonicalmodel.use_static_factory]'
1 warning
Copying 1 file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/USENET/build/classes
compile:
run:
DEBUG: nntp: newsrc loading /home/thufir/.newsrc
DEBUG: nntp: newsrc load: 6 groups in 31ms
[EL Info]: 2012-07-31 05:21:51.235--ServerSession(1478593)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504
[EL Info]: 2012-07-31 05:21:52.523--ServerSession(1478593)--file:/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/USENET/build/classes/_USENETPU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2012-07-31 05:21:52.672--ServerSession(1478593)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'usenet.HEADERFIELD' doesn't exist
Error Code: 1146
Call: ALTER TABLE HEADERFIELD DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_HEADERFIELD_ARTICLE_ID
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE HEADERFIELD DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_HEADERFIELD_ARTICLE_ID")
[EL Warning]: 2012-07-31 05:21:52.687--ServerSession(1478593)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'ARTICLE'
Error Code: 1051
Call: DROP TABLE ARTICLE
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP TABLE ARTICLE")
[EL Warning]: 2012-07-31 05:21:52.797--ServerSession(1478593)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'HEADERFIELD'
Error Code: 1051
Call: DROP TABLE HEADERFIELD
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP TABLE HEADERFIELD")
Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean <init>
INFO: [gwene.ca.craigslist.vancouver.labour.general, gwene.com.androidcentral, gwene.com.blogspot.emacsworld, gwene.com.blogspot.googlecode, gwene.com.blogspot.googlereader, gwene.com.economist]
Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 5
    at gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder.getMessage(NNTPFolder.java:330)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet.getMessage(Usenet.java:72)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.<init>(FetchBean.java:40)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.main(FetchBean.java:24)

Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 6
    at gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder.getMessage(NNTPFolder.java:330)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet.getMessage(Usenet.java:72)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.<init>(FetchBean.java:40)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.main(FetchBean.java:24)

Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 7
    at gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder.getMessage(NNTPFolder.java:330)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet.getMessage(Usenet.java:72)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.<init>(FetchBean.java:40)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.main(FetchBean.java:24)

Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 8
    at gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder.getMessage(NNTPFolder.java:330)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet.getMessage(Usenet.java:72)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.<init>(FetchBean.java:40)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.main(FetchBean.java:24)

Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 9
    at gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder.getMessage(NNTPFolder.java:330)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet.getMessage(Usenet.java:72)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.<init>(FetchBean.java:40)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.main(FetchBean.java:24)

Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 10
    at gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder.getMessage(NNTPFolder.java:330)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet.getMessage(Usenet.java:72)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.<init>(FetchBean.java:40)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.main(FetchBean.java:24)

Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 9
    at gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder.getMessage(NNTPFolder.java:330)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet.getMessage(Usenet.java:72)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.<init>(FetchBean.java:40)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.main(FetchBean.java:24)

Jul 31, 2012 5:21:53 AM net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet getMessage
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.MessageRemovedException: No such article: 10
    at gnu.mail.providers.nntp.NNTPFolder.getMessage(NNTPFolder.java:330)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model.Usenet.getMessage(Usenet.java:72)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.<init>(FetchBean.java:40)
    at net.bounceme.dur.usenet.driver.FetchBean.main(FetchBean.java:24)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

the enum:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.usenet.model;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.*;

public enum Usenet {

    INSTANCE;
    private final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Usenet.class.getName());
    private Properties props = new Properties();
    private Folder root = null;
    private Store store = null;
    private List<Folder> folders = new ArrayList<>();
    private Folder folder = null;

    Usenet() {
        LOG.fine("controller..");
        props = PropertiesReader.getProps();
        try {
            connect();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Usenet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "FAILED TO LOAD MESSAGES", ex);
        }
    }

    private void connect() throws Exception {
        LOG.fine("Usenet.connect..");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);
        store = session.getStore(new URLName(props.getProperty("nntp.host")));
        store.connect();
        root = store.getDefaultFolder();
        setFolders(Arrays.asList(root.listSubscribed()));
    }

    public void foo(String ng) throws Exception {
        folder = root.getFolder(ng);
        LOG.fine("opened the folder!!!!!");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    }

    public List<Message> getMessages(String newsgroup) throws Exception {
        LOG.fine("fetching.." + newsgroup);
        folder = root.getFolder(newsgroup);
        LOG.fine("opened the folder!!!!!");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        LOG.fine("opened: " + folder.getFullName());
        LOG.fine("opened: " + folder.getFullName());
        LOG.fine("opened: " + folder.getFullName());
        List<Message> messages = Arrays.asList(folder.getMessages());
        LOG.fine("..fetched " + folder);
        return messages;
    }

    public List<Folder> getFolders() {
        LOG.fine("folders " + folders);
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(folders);
    }

    private void setFolders(List<Folder> folders) {
        this.folders = folders;
    }

    public Message getMessage(String newsgroup, int i) {
        Message message = null;
        try {
            LOG.fine("fetching.." + newsgroup);
            folder = root.getFolder(newsgroup);
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            return folder.getMessage(i);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Usenet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            return message;//crummy
        }
    }
}
```

How can I handle this exception so that the program doesn't crash?

Answer (score 1):

You do a simple boolean check before attempting to process it:

```
if(!message.isExpunged)  
{  
     //process your message here  
}    
else{
    //log a message about it being expunged  
}
```

[API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Message.html#isExpunged%28%29)

public boolean isExpunged()

Checks whether this message is expunged. All other methods except getMessageNumber() are invalid on an expunged Message object.

Messages that are expunged due to an explict expunge() request on the containing Folder are removed from the Folder immediately. Messages that are externally expunged by another source are marked "expunged" and return true for the isExpunged() method, but they are not removed from the Folder until an explicit expunge() is done on the Folder.

See the description of expunge() for more details on expunge handling.